# How do I give my dropdownlist an id?

Tags: asp.net, razor

Hi I tried examples on the site but can't find solution.  I get no error but the id is not assigned to my dropdown list.  How do I assign an id to this dropdown list?

```
  @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString(), Selected = s.ToString().Equals("Day") }), new { @id = "listId" })
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Remove '@' from id . i.e new {id="listId"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString(), Selected = s.ToString().Equals("Day") }))
```

The first string argument in `@Html.DropDownList` is its id, remove the id u are giving as attribute.

Comment: The problem is, I have the multiples of the same id on the page and I was hoping to change the id at runtime.  When I do this the name attribute changes also.  Guess I'll have to find a workaround.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

try below code :-

```
 @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString(), Selected = s.ToString().Equals("Day") }), new { id = "listId" })
```

Comment: what are u saying?? which question?? @BhaveshPatadiya